# Deleting rows in between numbers and delete checkbox rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, rowdeleting

```
const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Potential Matrix");
  const rg=ss.getDataRange();
  const vs=rg.getValues();
  let d=0;
  vs.forEach(function(r,i){
    if(r.join('').length==0 || r.join('')=='false') {
      ss.deleteRow(i+1-d++);
    }
  });
  ss.insertRowBefore(1).getRange("1:1").clearFormat();
```

Hi @Cooper, thanks for that code. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to count the rows in between numbers 12, 13 and 14 as blank and therefore doesn't delete them. The original script you gave me worked when I didn't have checkboxes but now there are checkboxes it doesn't work. Is there any way of deleting rows including unticked/ticked checkboxes and empty data for columns that are not the checkboxes? I have added 'New Picture for reference' in my original post to show what I mean;

[New Picture for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1x0V.png)

Comment: Is there anything you've done to learn what the code does and attempted to modify it? SO is not a free coding service. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/

Comment: Please tell me what `r.join()` is for those rows.

Comment: Hi, yes I have created the code for a basic table from scratch and have learnt how to build the data validation and insert the checkboxes to the code myself. From my understanding the 'r.join()' for those rows is searching '(' ')' (which is equal to blank data). So the code is searching for blank data and if true then delete row. I am not sure how to adapt the code to search for checkboxes in the row and that's why I needed help, was not my intention to use this as a free coding service I am very happy to learn and be able to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

### How to check either your data contains checkboxes

- Apps Script feature the method [isChecked()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#ischecked) to inquire either a checkbox has been checked.
- You can use this method to inquire either a cell contains a checkbox at all:

  - If the cell is a checkbox and is checked - `isChecked()` will return `true`
  - If the cell is a checkbox and is not - `isChecked()` will return `false`
  - If the cell is not a checkbox at all - `isChecked()` will return `null`

Unfortunately from your question I cannot understand our exact question, but I hope that the following sample is helpful for you as a reference: it checks either a row contains checkboxes, and if it finds at least one checkbox - te row will be deleted:

```
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Potential Matrix");
  var row = 5;
  var lastColumn = ss.getLastColumn();
  var rg=ss.getRange(5,1,1, lastColumn);
  for (var i =0; i < lastColumn; i++){
    var checked = rg.getCell(1, (i+1)).isChecked();
    Logger.log(checked);
    if (checked != null){
      ss.deleteRow(row);
      return;
    }
  }
```